# Regex to extract first 4 letters in a word after a specific letter

Tags: regex

how can I get the letters before 'CA' using regex? for example, HSBCCASISSFMT  I want to get the output as HSBC but when I use this expression [^CA\b]* I only get HSB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of problem is often solvable via string splitting. Sometimes then also using a regex on the resultant substrings.

Here's an example in Python

```py
>>> s = "HSBCCASISSFMT"
>>> s.split("CA")           # use the string CA as a delimiter
['HSBC', 'SISSFMT']
>>> s.split("CA")[0][-4:]   # split, [0] first group, [-4:] last 4 chars
'HSBC'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this regex pattern `(.*)CA.*` or `^(.*)CA.*$`

```js
var text = "HSBCCASISSFMT"
var regExp = /^(.*)CA.*$/;

console.log(regExp.exec(text))
```

here is the link to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/p9qWDC/1)